# how show data one by one based its id (React JS)

Tags: reactjs

i want to show data in popup model using modal ReactBootstrap[image]

so I have this table in my react js, and I want if I click the column table it will show more detail about that data. if click column 1 it will show ID, name, age, fav colour, hobby, education, and many more. data that show in modal based on id clicked. anyone can help?

I use API so I get data using the JSON format and the format from API is a loop, but I want only show data that I clicked and not loop

I have this code

```
const tableData = response.data.data.map(post => {
  const { id, age, hobby, address, fav_colour, name } = post;

  return [
    [id],
    [name],
    [age],
    [address]
  ];
});
this.setState({
  data: tableData,
  isLoading: false
});
})

componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
}


render() {

  const Popup = () => {
    const [lgShow, setLgShow] = React.useState(false);
    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => setLgShow(true)}>Large modal</Button>
        <Modal
          size="lg"
          show={lgShow}
          onHide={() => setLgShow(false)}
          aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-lg">
              Data {id}
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>

            <div><b>ID</b></div><br />
            <div>{ID}</div>

            <div><b>Name</b></div><br />
            <div>{name}</div>

            <div><b>Age</b></div><br />
            <div>{age}</div>

            <div><b>Addres</b></div><br />
            <div>{address}</div>

            <div><b>Hobby</b></div><br />
            <div>{hobby}</div>

            <div><b>Favourite Colour</b></div><br />
            <div>{fav_colour}</div>

            <div><b>Education</b></div><br />
            <div>{education}</div>


          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  };
  const { isLoading } = this.state;
  const columns = ["ID", "Name", "Age", "Address"];

  const options = {
    filterType: "dropdown",
    responsive: "scroll",
    selectableRows: false,
  }
};

return (
  <div>
    <center><h3>Data</h3></center><br />

    {!isLoading ? (
      <MUIDataTable
        data={this.state.data}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />)
      : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}

    <Popup></Popup>
  </div>
);

      }
}

export default App
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?
What have you tried till now?

Comment: what should i do if i want to show data in each row i click and show all data in modal

Comment: Make a modal component, that accepts row attributes as prop.

Render that component on click (using a flag).